# How to extract javascript linkname using regex?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am using JMeter 2.9 and would like to extract javascript link names embedded in a page.

Given below is the string:

```
<a href="javascript:viewResource('rsd51885775');">Introduction to HTML5</a>
```

Now using regex, I would like to extract 'Introduction to HTML5' text.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML, use [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to extract `Introduction to HTML5`, then I'd use

```
/<a.+?>(.+)<\/a>/
```

[Demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/lB7mV1)

If you only want to extract the text of the links which link to `javascript:viewResource()` then go for

```
/<a.+javascript:viewResource\('.+'\).+>(.+)<\/a>/
```

[Demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/oW1kK4)

Sample usage:

```
alert("<a href=\"javascript:viewResource('rsd51885775');\">Introduction to HTML5</a>"
  .match(/<a.+javascript:viewResource\('.+'\).+>(.+)<\/a>/)[1]);
```

---

If you mean `rsd51885775`, then I'd use

```
/<a.+\('(\w+)'\).+?>/
```

as your regex.
**Note** that `\w` allows `a-zA-Z0-9` and `_`! If you don't want to allow underscores and/or only lower-case letters then you're better off with `[a-z0-9]` instead of `\w`.
[Demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/eF6nV3)

Comment: <a href="javascript:viewResource.+?;">(.+?)</a>- - - This one worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use CSS/JQuery extractor

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
 (?:<a href=\"javascript:[^\"]+\">)(.*)(?=<\/a>)
```

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hO5bB9)**

**Explanation :**

[image]

Comment: No, this is giving me all other text which are not even JS links. I would like to extract the hrefs containing this pattern ** <a href="javascript:viewResource(**);". In the above string, I would like to extract Introduction to HTML5 only.